# Using .proto files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to get to grips with protobuf-net as I believe this is the right tool to aid me in deserialising a protobuf created file. I have managed to find the *.proto* files relating to the file in question so I believe I have all the raw information required to deal with the file. Here's my problem:

From the [protobuf-net github page](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) it says you must decorate your classes like so:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
class Address {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Line1 {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Line2 {get;set;}
}
```

My question is, do I need to create a new class in my project from each of the .proto files I've found and line by line convert these to the above format? Is there instead a way I can reference the .proto files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: the VB.NET tooling for protogen has been implemented and is now available via protobuf-net at https://protogen.marcgravell.com; the command-line tool isn't updated yet, but will be in the next few days (it is the same code, just published differently).

---

There is a .proto codegen tool for protobuf-net. The version of protogen that shipped [with r668](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-net/downloads) includes VB.NET support but is not up-to-date with "proto3" and various other protobuf concepts. In protobuf-net 2.3 the protogen tool was completely rewritten to be fully managed and to include modern .proto concepts, *but*: while the API is language extensible, I *have not* implemented a VB.NET generator, mostly because I'm not a reliable source of wisdom for writing idiomatic VB.NET code.

If you want to implement a VB.NET generator, it wouldn't be much work in real terms, and I'd gladly take a PR.

Comment: I'd love to contribute, but I'm an amateur at best and unintentionally obfuscate at worst.That being said, if I manage to get anything working I'll share it!

Comment: As a side comment to make sure I'm on the right page, protobuf-net will still 100% work in vb.net it's just there's no automatic way to generate vb.net classes from a .proto file correct?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg correct; the library doesn't know or care what language you are using - it just looks at the metadata.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg if I get time, I'll see if I can VB-ify the existing code; I'm slightly cautious of it being a monstrosity, but I'll give it a go...

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg initial port is complete but untested - it processes "descriptor.proto" (Google's metadata bootstrap) successfully into VB.NET that compiles, so there shouldn't be much left to do; for your tracking purposes: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/pull/365

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg and: merged - available on website only right now - I haven't updated the CLI tools, but this is just a matter of hitting "publish" if you desperately need that. Very interested in your feedback.

Comment: I've had a look at the website and there's a few things that haven't work (mostly due to my ineptitude I believe). Firstly: REM #error extensions not yet implemented. Secondly is there a way to use the website to convert multiple files at once (I have a bunch of files that reference each other! Here's what I'm trying to convert: https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/tree/master/Resources/Protobufs/dota (I believe that project converted using your code (although not to vb).

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg indeed, extensions is just a "I haven't done that yet" - it isn't a huge piece of work, just: the plane landed, etc (literally). I'll see what I can do later. On the topic of multiple files: the website doesn't offer that simply due to UI complications and lack of time, but the CLI tool does. I'll try to implement the extensions and get the CLI deployed. Note: even without multiple files, *as a temporary workarorund* you can usually simply concatenate multiple files into one to run it through a codegen.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg just looked at the `generate-base.bat` and indeed that looks like the r668 version of protogen; the 2.3.0 version has slightly different parameter usage (to match `protoc`), and includes wildcard usage (`*.proto`, etc)

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg website and downloadable tool (look for "1.0.3") updated to support extensions; you should be looking for `--vb_out` (or use `--help`) at the command-line; let me know about any problems

Comment: thank you for your hard work. I've found a few files cause the protogen application to crash (protogen has stopped working - last line in cmd: steamdatagram_messages.proto(1,1,1,7): warning: no syntax specified; it is strongly recommended to specify 'syntax="proto2";' or 'syntax="proto3";') The files from the linked repo that cause this are: base_gcmessages.proto
dota_gcmessages_client.proto
steamdatagram_messages.proto
It does look like the .vb files created by are as expected though - so the crash doesn't seem to effect functionality.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg fair enough; I'll try to download those and see what happened when I get a moment. The warning message shouldn't be related, but thanks for including it.

Comment: "MarcGravell I'm also getting a lot of errors of the type: '__pbn__ClientSessionId' is already declared as 'Private __pbn__ClientSessionid As Integer?' in this class. Also: Attribute 'ProtoContractAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times. I'm still going though the files, I'll keep posting as/when i have more details!

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg the crash is because [I'm an idiot](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/commit/177460063a59abbf023adb1392372f5076509424) - looking to see why the client session id is playing up

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg well that was a fun set of fixes! I now have recursive mode working such that `protogen --proto_path=c:\code\SteamKit\Resources\Protobufs --vb_out=c:\code\protogen\vb **/*.proto` works and generates **everything** successfully. There's still a few quirks I'm working through, though; the "already declared" errors are because the same types are in multiple .proto files without packages, so they're all going into the root namespace. Any suggestions? use the file as the package? I don't think you're meant to use more than one - pretty sure protoc uses "no namespace" in this case.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg I'm also seeing some overflows on default values - looking into that (edit: fixed and deployed)

Comment: I've not yet been able to work out how to deal with the 'already declared' errors. I'll keep at it and let you know here if I figure  something out.

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg the "already declared" will happen if you have multiple competing definitions of the same thing; for example [`CMsgProtoBufHeader`](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/blob/master/Resources/Protobufs/portal/steammessages.proto#L1-L7) vs [`CMsgProtoBufHeader`](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/blob/master/Resources/Protobufs/csgo/steammessages.proto#L23-L36) - both of which are in the root namespace. I'm open to suggestions here: should protogen optionally infer a package name (namespace) from the filename if no package name is specified? should the package name be a cmd arg?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg perhaps something like `--defaultpackage=Foo` or `--defaultpackage=#FILE#` or `defaultpackage=#DIR#` - in the case of the first link, `#FILE#` would use `streammessages` (which would still be ambiguous), where-as `#DIR#` would use `portal` / `csgo` / etc

Comment: Certainly the #DIR# would work for my needs. Although for more generic use could we use #FILE#-#DIR#. It's a little messy but it might be better for the general case? Just  my 2 cents, you've got the experience here! :D

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg oh, my intent was that it would basically be `defaultPath = defaultPath?.Replace("#FILE#", nameWithoutExtension).Replace('#DIR#', finalFolderName)` - which would allow exactly that; I'll see if I can hack that in later

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg so 1.0.5 is "up"; the following works for me and compiles **all** the VB in one project with zero errors or warnings: `protogen --proto_path=c:\code\SteamKit\Resources\Protobufs --vb_out=c:\code\protogen\vb **/*.proto --package=#DIR#.#FILE# +names=original` - note that the `+names=original` is only required for **one file** - one of the `tf_beta` ones; you could also just rename that one field in the .proto (protobuf doesn't care much about names) if you want prettier VB casing (`matchgroup` vs `match_group` - 25 vs 41 IIRC).

Comment: I'm  probably making a rookie mistake here, but I get "File not found: Protobufs\csgo\base_gcmessages.proto" for all the files (the proto file name  changes ofc). I've set up my folders exactly as you have (based on your paths) and as far as I can tell it doesn't matter where protogen is run from (I've tried a few options, but I don't think it would matter anyway). Is it possible it's looking for - "Protobufs\csgo\base_gcmessages.proto" - but not adding the "c:\code\SteamKit\Resources\" part of the file address?

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg huh; that's weird; I have a repro, though - checking now; sorry about this

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg change the `--proto_path` to end with a trailing slash - i.e. "c:\code\SteamKit\Resources\Protobufs\" in my example; no idea (yet) why this worked differently on my laptop - it all comes down to `MakeRelativePath`

Comment: It works! All files successfully imported! Thanks for all  your help with this, let me know if you need any sort of testing done :) Now for me to figure out what i'm doing with the data!